# Render mail in html page

Tags: php, html, email, iframe, embed

Im trying to render emails on my site. The problem is that these emails contains html and css, which means that I suddenly can get a green background on the page. its not rendering the mail properly. Sometimes I see html tags and so on.( se picture in the link below)

http://nullpointer.se/pic.png

I hade my thoughts on iframe. But as you can see i dont have a link refere to in the iframe src parameter.

This is parts the code that im using (MVC)

This is the Model function that im using

```
function get_mail_num($email_number)
{
    $connection = imap_open($this->server, $this->user, $this->password);

    $mail['overview'] = imap_fetch_overview($connection,$email_number,0);
        $mail['message'] = imap_fetchbody($connection,$email_number,2);

        imap_close($connection);

        return $mail;
}
```

This is the controller function that are featching the mails and sending them to the view

```
function index() // the inbox
{
    $this->load->model('mail_model');
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->load->library('table');  
    // config for table
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->mail_model->get_size();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://nullpointer.se/mailendar/mail/index';
    $config['num_links'] = 4;

    if(!$this->uri->segment(3)){$offset = 1;}else{$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);}
    $records = $this->mail_model->get_mail_header($config['per_page'],$offset);
    $data['output'] ="";
    $id = $offset;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($records);$i++)
    {
        if(empty($records[$i]->subject))
        {
            $records[$i]->subject = "No Subject";
        }
        $data['output'].= '<div onclick="funct('.$id.')" class="toggler '.($records[$i]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        $data['output'].= '<span  class="subject">'.$records[$i]->subject.'</span> ';
        $data['output'].= '<span  class="from">'.$records[$i]->from.'</span>';
        $data['output'].= '<span class="date">on '.$records[$i]->date.'</span>';
        $data['output'].= '</div>';

        $data['output'].= "<div class='body' id ='{$id}'> </div>";
        $id++;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page'] = "pages/mail";
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);   

}
```

This is the view that shows everything

```
    <div id="main" class="span-19 last colborder">
        <h2>Mail</h2>
            <?php echo $output//$this->table->generate(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id = "sidebar" class = "span-4 last">
            <h2>Options</h2>
            <a href = "Convert" class ="button">Convert</a>
            <a href = "Remove" class ="button">Remove</a>
            <a href = "Move" class ="button">Move</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please link to a larger image. Your 3600x1080 PNG is far too small for my 90 inch monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably mentioned the easiest solution. You could simply create a simple email viewer, ex: viewer.php?id=123 for email id 123, then display the viewer through a simple iframe:

```
<iframe width="[YOUR_WIDTH]" HEIGHT="[YOUR_HEIGHT]" src="viewer.php?id=123"></iframe>
```

All you need to do in your viewer is to get the email body from your model, the echo it.

Comment: Thanks!!

I created a new controller method that echos out in a iframe (invoked by js).